# Python design pattern: class that returns different objects depending on parameters

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

This question concerns design patterns in Python and is addressed to the software designers.

I have several classes inherited from the same abstract class (all they have a similar interface, but the member functions have very different implementations). I want to make a class (or something else) that combines (wraps) all of them. By combining I mean a pattern that creates and returns an object a certain class depending on the input parameters. The most trivial solution is a Python function:

```
def fabric_function(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, float):
        return Class1(arg)
    if isinstance(arg, str):
        return Class2(arg)
```

Is there a better pattern available to do it? I would really prefer it to be a class that returns either object of `Class1` or `Class2` depending on parameters. I want the user to make an instance of a class `Class` that operates as an instance of the `Class1` or `Class2` depending on input parameters so the user does not have to make a decision on which of them to use and the output from `type(obj)` should be `Class` in all cases. In this case, I could modify the member function `__new__` responsible for the object making process, but I am not sure it is a clean way to do it. Maybe I should use multiple inheritance and decide in the constructor which parent class to inherit for real?

Comment: *and the output from type(obj) should be Class in all cases*.  How hard of a requirement is this?  What’s the intent?  It’s easy to have a Class1 Class2 factory.  Having one that says Class in both cases is *possible* (using `type` to create a class on the fly) but frankly it’s a horrible hack and neither clear to consumers nor necessarily good for things like `isinstance`.  Smells like an XY problem if thats a hard req.

Comment: It is not that hard but I don't want the user to be aware of the existence of Class1 and Class2, they are technical classes and have nothing to do with the library interface he/she is going to use.

Comment: and like i said, it is a *hack*.  you're introducing weird behavior for something that an actual *end user* would never care about and a *programmer user* would hate.  XY problem.  in any case, pythonic class check behavior revolves around `isinstance`, not `type`.  that's core enough to the language that linters complain about `type`, rather than `isinstance` use.  so, again, an informed user would not use `type` in their code, though they might in the repl.

Comment: This sounds like severe OO abuse and you haven't provided any justification for *"I don't want the user to be aware of the existence of Class1 and Class2"*. Is it permissions or security-through-obscurity, e.g. one is `Employee.request_pay_rise` and the other is `Manager.approve_pay_rise`? Please show more specifics about Class1, Class2 and why they manage to be sibling classes yet you want to obscure their relation. If *"they're technical classes and have nothing to do with the library interface he/she is going to use"* then just give the common parent class an obscure name, prefaced with "_"

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `Class1` and `Class2` are related somehow (eg, "Square" and "Circle" are both "Figures" ). What you are describing is an Abstract Factory.

You need a class exposing a `Create()` method, accepting the bare minimum context that would help you find out what's the concrete implementation to instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar once using a dictionary. I requires the init functions of your derived classes to have the same signatures in order to work.

Use a dictionary with some immutable type of your choice as key and put the classnames as values:

```
TYPE_MAP = {typeA: Class1,
            typeB: Class2,
            typeC: Class3}

def fabric_function(arg):
    return TYPE_MAP[type(arg)](arg)
```

I'm not exactly sure how pythonic/clean you consider this but it helped me greatly in avoiding this `if isinstance...` chain you posted above. Also it is very easy to extend as you only have to adjust the dictionary and not the factory function.